# Is there a way to track what Witcher items I have already crafted?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In The Witcher 3, you craft Witcher items. These items can be upgraded.

Is there a way in-game to track what Witcher items I already have and which ones I need to craft?

For instance, I don't want to craft a 2nd pair of Feline Boots if I already have them. The only way I currently know of is to go to my stash and check to see if I already have the item stashed away.

Comment: As of the moment, there is no way to track this in-game.

Comment: @DangerZone - that sounds like it should be an answer to the question

Comment: @Pyritie, unfortunately, I don't really have proof other than "I've looked everywhere in my own game", but I can post it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the moment, there is no way to track this in-game.
I don't recall seeing anything about it in the 1.07 change log either (although I haven't played it since 1.06...)

What I did to make it easier was the old pen and paper method and wrote it down myself (after double-crafting some Ursine boots).